# Order by innerJoin table with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a OneToMany relationship between two entities: Shop and Comment. I would like to display a list of Shops ordered by the date of the last review they received.
This is what I tried so far:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->innerJoin('s.reviews', 'r', 'WITH', 'r.shop = s.id')
            ->orderBy('r.createdAt') // <- that does nothing on the order of the shops
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

This returns all the shops, but they aren't ordered at all...

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  Do you even get a result set back?

Comment: Did you try `->orderBy('r.createdAt', 'DESC')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use it inside your ShopRepository you should try it this way

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('s, MAX(r.createdAt) AS maxCreatedAt')
            ->from('AppBundle:Comment', 'r')
            ->join('AppBundle:Shop', 's', 'WITH', 'r.shop = s.id')
            ->groupBy('s')
            ->orderBy('maxCreatedAt', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Don't forget to modify the bundle namespaces (AppBundle) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks alot, I never thought of it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `OrderBy` directly on your `@ORM\OneToMany mappedBy` relation like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany...
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "DESC"})
 */
private $reviews;
```